# Find first rows of change in historical table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have an old legacy table in MS SQL Server 2008 which needs to be cleaned. Table contains daily rows for multiple products and their daily change parameter. The procedure filling the table is not optimized and is making duplicate rows for each day where only the change should be noted.

Now I already fixed the daily procedure to insert only changed values but now I need to clean the original table.

My plan was to make an extract of only the relevant rows (where change was made MIN(C) Group By B) and insert them into a new table and use this new table. I tried with RANK() but no success, Group By didn't work as the change parameter repeats over time.

This is how it looks like (column A has multiple values, 123, 345, 567 etc. so it need to be in a group also):

a test fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0da5a/3

```
A    B    C
123  0    20130101
123  0    20130102
123  1    20130103
123  1    20130104
123  0    20130105
123  2    20130106
123  2    20130107
123  2    20130108
123  0    20130109
123  3    20130110
123  3    20130111
123  3    20130112
```

Expected result is:

```
123 0 20130101
123 1 20130103
123 0 20130105
123 2 20130106
123 0 20130109
123 3 20130110
```

(edit: added column A to expected result)

Comment: Looking at your Expected result, is the values in column A irrelevant?

Comment: No, I forgot to add it. A column does contain more "product IDs" as I specified above the test fiddle. Also t-clausen.dk correctly used it in 'partition by A'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (A decimal(8,0), B int, C decimal(8,0))
INSERT INTO T1 (A, B, C) VALUES (123, 0, 20130101),
(123, 0, 20130102),(123, 1, 20130103),
(123, 1, 20130104),(123, 0, 20130105),
(123, 2, 20130106),(123, 2, 20130107),
(123, 2, 20130108),(123, 0, 20130109),
(123, 3, 20130110),(123, 3, 20130111),
(123, 3, 20130112),(123, 3, 20130113)


;with x as
(
  select t1.A, t1.B, t1.C, 
  row_number() over (partition by a order by c) rn 
  from T1
)
select x1.A, x1.B, x1.C 
from x x1
left join x x2
on x1.rn = x2.rn +1 and x1.A = x2.A
where x2.A is null
or x1.B <> x2.B
```

Result:

```
A   B   C
123 0   20130101
123 1   20130103
123 0   20130105
123 2   20130106
123 0   20130109
123 3   20130110
```